# How to crrate this joining particle splash screen on android

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

Hello i want to have [this splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3O5S.gif) on my android app how can do it

Comment: this doesn't really have all that much to do with android, first you're going to need that graphic from a designer in a format, whether it's json or a gif or something else, then you just need to load it, so - do you have the graphic and what format is it ? after you answer that question you can easily do research on how to load a file of that type, so i'm not really sure if this is worth asking here, seems like something you could resolve yourself with some more research, if you've struggled to achieve this, post what you've tried and what isn't working

Comment: Its a png rendered with the file ParticleLogoView.java witch is obsficated so i decided to test that so i replaced the png with apk editor pro and boom it works [here is a gif](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/258999527783137280/947937137502847027/Screenshot_20220228-192050_X_Locker.gif)